Using SendGrid with Azure node.js programming model v4
My goal is to send email from an Azure Static Web App contact page using an Azure Function. I have managed to get that working as described below, so my question is "how can this be done better in Azure Functions?"

Apparently one cannot use Azure Communications Services from within an Azure Function to send email. I was able to get this to work in the local static web app (SWA) emulation, but it fails silently when running from within Azure.

I punted and created a SendGrid account. This offers 100 free messages a day for free, so it's a good alternative.

All of the reference material I can find references integration using Azure node.js programming model v3, which includes function.json configuration files. There is even a Microsoft Docs github repo issue regarding this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/119439

Since Azure node.js programming model v4 (hereafter just "v4") is the default and the standard, I decided I didn't want to use v3.

SendGrid sample code works nearly out of the box, but when you wrap it in async function for v4, you need to await the ".send" operation.  If you don't, the function will actually exit and you will get a response value of "unexpected state" (using my code; the message is still sent in a local environment, but that cannot be counted upon). This is where my weakness with JS async comes into play, because I thought then/catch were the other way of dealing with promises.


Here is my working code:
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");
const mta = require("@sendgrid/mail");

app.http("sendGrid", {
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    const key = process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY;
    var response = 'unexpected state'
    var code = 200;

    // Authenticate
    mta.setApiKey(key);

    // Timestamp for this invocation
    const timestamp = new Date(Date.now());

    // Build a message
    const content = {
      to: "user@domain", /* <== replace with your target email address */
      from: "user@domain", /* <== replace with authenticated sender address */
      subject: `SendGrid message ${timestamp}`,
      text: `SendGrid message body text ${timestamp}`,
      html: `SendGrid message body html <strong>${timestamp}</strong>`
    };

    await mta.send(content)
            .then(() => { 
                response = `message ${timestamp} sent`;
                code = 200;
            })
            .catch((thrown) => { 
                response = `message not sent ${thrown}`;
                code = 500;
            });
    
    context.log(response);

    return { status: code, body: response };
  }
});


To send email from an Azure Static Web App  using an Azure Function of v4 you have to add frontend app to call the API endpoint. I used  _src/index.html_ file to fetch the text from the API function and display it on the screen which acts like no framework .
I used this MSDOC to add an API to Azure Static Web Apps with Azure Functions .
Below   simple HTML  code  is used to trigger/display  the results Azure Function for sending an email using SendGrid.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API Response Display</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .response {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .success {
            background-color: #e6ffed;
            border-color: #a3d9a5;
        }
        .failure {
            background-color: #ffe6e6;
            border-color: #d9a5a5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>API Response Display</h1>
    <button id="fetchButton">Fetch API Response</button>
    <div id="responseContainer" class="response"></div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('fetchButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            const responseContainer = document.getElementById('responseContainer');
            responseContainer.innerHTML = 'Fetching...';

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/httpTrigger');
                const data = await response.json();

                if (response.ok) {
                    responseContainer.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="success">
                            <h2>Success</h2>
                            <pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
                        </div>
                    `;
                } else {
                    responseContainer.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="failure">
                            <h2>Failure</h2>
                            <pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
                        </div>
                    `;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                responseContainer.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="failure">
                        <h2>Error</h2>
                        <pre>${error}</pre>
                    </div>
                `;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Git Folder Strucure:


Now change the git yml according to your Folder Strucure

 app_location to  "./src" 
  api_location to  "./api1"
 output_location to  "." 

Refer to this SO  for yml workflow configuration file in Static Web App.
Deployment  Status

The endpoint of the function app must have the /api prefix, since Static Web Apps matches requests made to /api.
The existing Azure Functions app  exposes an endpoint via the following sample example Url
https:/nameofazuresataticwebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/functionname as show in the below image.
Azure Functions app with  Azure Static Output:


Azure Static Output:



This is an excellent and complete answer, and I will accept it as correct even though I have not verified it. My original "working code" did NOT work in the actual Azure environment, but only in the local test environment.  I abandoned the use of Azure entirely because it is far too much effort to accomplish things I can do easily in AWS.
